# Rcov showing spec'd methods as not covered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rcov

I kind of have a mess going right now, but the gist is I can run rake spec:rcov successfully and get a report but all it shows as being covered is the "def" lines of my code. None of the code inside the methods is being run according to rcov.

Specifically I have a disp_price_txt method in my application helper. I have written specs, that pass in rspec, in spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb. However rcov is not showing the code as being run.

My gems are below. I'm using ree 1.8.7-head. I started out by installing Metrical and was going to uses simplecov until I realized it was for 1.9 only. Then I went back to rcov.

rails (3.1.1)
rspec (2.8.0, 2.7.0)
rspec-core (2.8.0, 2.7.1)
rspec-expectations (2.8.0, 2.7.0)
rspec-mocks (2.8.0, 2.7.0)
rspec-rails (2.8.1, 2.7.0)
rcov (0.9.11)

Hopefully this is enough to get some input. If any other info is needed let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: I installed a test project and got rspec and rcov working right away. I just noticed that when I run rcov on the test project it outputs the  rspec progress. However it doesn't do that on the main app. I'm running rcov directly using -Ispec spec/**/*.rb.

Comment: Also all rspec gems are version 2.8.0, rspec-rails 2.8.1 and rcov is 1.0.0 for both the test project and main app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I was missing "require 'rspec/autorun'" in my spec_helper.rb. I inherited this project so I'm not sure if it was removed. My guess is the rspec gem was updated but the spec_helper.rb was from an older gem. Anyway it's solved and everything is working!!!